# Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC when adding data validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

```
int row_index = 2;
foreach (DataRow row in dataTableSourceSystem.Rows)
{
    xlWorkSheet.get_Range("AM" + row_index.ToString(), System.Reflection.Missing.Value).Value2 = row["LookupShortName"].ToString();
    row_index++;
}
Range range = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("G2,G50");

range.Validation.Add(XlDVType.xlValidateList, XlDVAlertStyle.xlValidAlertStop, XlFormatConditionOperator.xlBetween, "=$AM2:$AM50", System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
```

The last line is throwing an exception `0x800A03EC`

`Am2` to `Am50` has values.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
Range range = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("G2:G50");
```

You have `G2,G50` where the comma is apparently a "union" operator.  Instead you want a range operator (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.get_range.aspx)) to match the same sized range AM2:AM50.

Comment: Even this is not resolving the problem

Comment: I changed the answer after some more research.

Comment: @agentnega The validation range does not need to be the same size as the range it is applied to.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this exception and I figured out it's because of Worksheet.Selection.
I didn't figure it out yet how is this linked with Data Validation, but I will look into it and let you know.

In order to solve your issue, you should do something like this:

```
 xlWorkSheet.Range["$A$1"].Select();
 Range range = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("G2,G50");
 Validation v = range.Validation;

 // you might want to delete validation first
 // v.Delete();

 v.Add(XlDVType.xlValidateList, XlDVAlertStyle.xlValidAlertStop, XlFormatConditionOperator.xlBetween, "=$AM2:$AM50", System.Reflection.Missing.Value);

 // some other useful stuff for you
 // v.ErrorMessage = "You need to fill in a value from the validation list.";
 // v.InCellDropdown = true;
```